# Control of Audio Playback in Presenter View in Keynote?

Tags: audio, keynote

I am a speech scientist, presenting speech sounds for listeners in a lecture. I have multiple audio clips (each a separate .wav file) embedded in my slide, and I want to be able to play each audiofile out so that I can demonstrate aspects of each sound.

This means I want to be able to:

1. completely control playback. I don't see a control icon when I mouseover the locations of my soundfile icons (although they are visible in composition view, they aren't in the presentation view). Right now I click or press the and the clips play back one at a time, in the designated playback order. It doesn't matter where I click on the screen, only the next clip in the order will play back.
2. play clips any number of times I wish, and in any order (to show fine differences in the acoustic signal that enable the sounds to be differentiated.

Is there any way to do these things? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> To get full playback controls in Presentation mode in Keynote, all you
>   need to do is make the placed audio icon larger, then move your mouse
>   into that larger region while in presentation playback mode.

- The controller is not visible while editing your presentation, so yust make it large square and then check in presentation view.

> As the size of the audio icon increases, you’ll see more and more
>   control options when you hover over the region in presentation mode.
>   Once you reach 400 pixels in size, you’ll see all the same controller
>   features you get with a QuickTime movie.
>
> Note that when you’re in edit mode, you’ll see an increasingly-large
>   version of the Sound icon as you increase its size. As with the
>   standard-sized icon, though, this icon will not appear in presentation
>   mode. To access the audio playback controls while in presentation
>   mode, just move your mouse into the region of the large icon, and the
>   controller will appear.
>   
>   Source: http://www.macworld.com/article/1142542/keynoteaudio.html

Comment: Thanks for your response--however, I seem to be unable to resize my audio icons. I'm running Keynote 6.2 under Mavericks 10.9.2.  My clips are .wav files, and the audio icons display as an oval, with a right-pointing arrow and speaker. No matter how I try to resize them, I cannot. My resizing options in the Inspector are grayed out.

Comment: see update for editing

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to convert the audio file to video with a waveform (for some reason, video files show a control but audio files don't).

Install [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) and run this in the command line:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "/choose/your/folder/input.mp3" -filter_complex \
"[0:a]showwaves=s=150x100:scale=lin:mode=cline:colors=white:rate=25,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a "/choose/your/folder/output.mp4"
```

Note: You can change `150x100` to `1500x1000` for example, if you want a higher resolution.

It will end up looking like this:

[image]

You'll be able to toggle pause/play **once the video has started playing**.

If you have more than one video, you won't be able to click-start at random. Clicking will follow the order you specified in the **Build Order** (animations) panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd>/<kbd>l</kbd> keys on the keyboard to rewind, pause, and fast forward, but you can't access the audio like in powerpoint.